# Which technology to use for fast cache API in .net

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, wcf, grpc

I have a complex caching mechanism which sits inside my app and uses dictionaries to retrieves the data.
The code loads the data from the database and store it in dictionaries in the memory of the app itself.
I want to move the cache out from the app and build a cache API.

The reasons are:

1. Reduce the time it takes to the app to start
2. Make the memory footprint of the app small.
3. To allow other apps to get data from the cache.

The most important thing in the new cache API is the speediness of the API.
I'm moving from dictionaries in the app's memory to an external API and this will slow down the app.

What option will give me the highest speed?

1. .Net Core Rest API
2. GRPC
3. WCF
4. Other option?

Thank you.

Comment: WFC is based on SOAP and uses a standard XML schema, which may be slower. On the other hand, Web API can utilize any text format, so it is faster and is the first choice for lightweight services. WCF is the ideal choice when you need to create services that support unique solutions such as duplex communication and one-way messaging. When you need to use HTTP to build resource-oriented services that can utilize the full capabilities of HTTP, you should choose Web API.

Comment: gRPC uses HTTP/2 which is much faster than HTTP/1.1 used in REST by default. gRPC uses protocol buffers to serialize payload data, which is binary and small.But gRPC also has shortcomings. Not all browsers currently support gRPC.